# How do I remove the default link color of the html hyperlink 'a' tag?

Tags: html, css, anchor

The default link color is blue.
How do I remove the default link color of the html hyperlink tag `<a>`?

Comment: Default text color for `<a>` is blue. What's your problem now?

Comment: I am trying to get if dint give any color to <a>, I don't want it to show in blue color. It in the default text color, the text color may be black or blue like that...

Comment: @Terry_Brown - I found this question quite useful, as I wanted to find the "color:inherit" answer below, which is what I believe the question was relating too...

Answer (score 695, accepted):

The [inherit value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit):

```
a { color: inherit; }
```

… will cause the element to take on the colour of its parent (which is what I think you are looking for).

A live demo follows:

```css
a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<p>The default color of the html element is black. The default colour of the body and of a paragraph is inherited. This
  <a href="http://example.com">link</a> would normally take on the default link or visited color, but has been styled to inherit the color from the paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 110):

Try something like this:

```
a {
    color: #0060B6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color:#00A0C6; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    cursor:pointer;  
}
```

If `text-decoration` doesn't work, change it to:

```
text-decoration: none !important;
```

The `!important` rule overrides every other styling to the `text-decoration` attribute. You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp).

Comment: moreover, if you want to prevent the change of color for a specific link after pressing it, add inside the a tag: <A STYLE="text-decoration:none; color=[select your favorite...]" HREF="link.html">
test link</A>

Comment: `<a style="text-decorations:none; color:inherit;>` = winning

Comment: @DanBradbury remove 's' in text-decorations.

`<a style="text-decoration:none; color:inherit;>`

Answer (score 39):

If you don't want to see the underline and default color which is provided by the browser, you can keep the following code in the top of your main.css file. If you need different color and decoration styling you can easily override the defaults using the below code snippet.

```
 a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: inherit;
 }
```

Comment: Useful but generic patterns could cause problems if not carefully planned... 
USE WITH CAUTION

Answer (score 22):

```
.cancela,.cancela:link,.cancela:visited,.cancela:hover,.cancela:focus,.cancela:active{
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I felt it necessary to post the above class definition, many of the answers on SO miss some of the states

Answer (score 19):

This is also possible:

```css
a {
  all: unset;
}
```

> unset: This keyword indicates to change all the properties applying to
> the element or the element's parent to their parent value if they are
> inheritable or to their initial value if not. unicode-bidi and
> direction values are not affected.

Source: [Mozilla description of all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all)

Comment: You _could_, but just because you can doesn't mean you should. I'd say given the nature of this rule you should really include a little more about what it actually does.

Comment: Apparently `color: unset` also works. I removed framework colors from the element, then wrapped the element and set my custom color on that wrapper so the color is inherited.

Answer (score 8):

You have to use `CSS`. Here's an example of changing the default link color, when the link is just sitting there, when it's being hovered and when it's an active link.

```css
a:link {
  color: red;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

a:active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href='http://google.com'>Google</a>
```

Answer (score 8):

Simply add this in `CSS`,

```
a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

that's it, done.

Comment: I don't know, what is the issue with down voter, believe me this works...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [System Color (18.2)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#system-colors) values, introduced with CSS 2.0, but **deprecated in CSS 3**.

```
a:link, a:hover, a:active { color: WindowText; }
```

That way your anchor links will have the same color as normal document text on this system.

Answer (score 2):

I had this challenge when I was working on a Rails 6 application using Bootstrap 4.

My challenge was that I didn't want this styling to override the default link styling in the application.

So I created a **CSS** file called `custom.css` or `custom.scss`.

And then defined a new **CSS rule** with the following **properties**:

```
.remove_link_colour {
  a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
      color: inherit;
      text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

Then I called this rule wherever I needed to override the default link styling.

```
<div class="product-card__buttons">
  <button class="btn btn-success remove_link_colour" type="button"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %></button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger remove_link_colour" type="button"><%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></button>
</div>
```

This solves the issue of overriding the default link styling and removes the default **colour**, **hover**, **focus**, and **active** styling in the buttons only in places where I call the **CSS rule**.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
  a {
    cursor: default;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a:link{color:inherit;}
```

this is the simple one line can do all stuffs for you <3

Answer (score -1):

I too wanted to remove the default blue link color of a tag.
As I was using bootstrap version 5 I decided to look for the solution in bootstrap documentation.
I searched for "link color" and the result was this link: "https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/colored-links/"

bootstrap version 5.0 has a class to customise the link colors which I found very helpful and also I was able to change the default blue color of my 'a' tag without any fuss.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Here are two methods to remove the default link color:

**Method 1: Remove default color:

```
a, a:visited, a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**Method 2: Using a specific color like

```
a, a:visited, a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This will work

```
    a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
        outline: none;
    }
```

What this does is removes the outline for all the three pseudo-classes.

Comment: Please provide a little more explanation as to why this works.

Comment: The question isn't asking about the outline

Answer (score -2):

```
<style>
a {
color:      ;
}
</style>
```

This code changes the color from the default to what is specified in the style. Using a:hover, you can change the color of the text from the default on hover.

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how it answers the question, so that others can learn.