# how to disable the default css color of an anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to remove the default CSS of anchor tag using jquery/css.
 I am allowing users to select  [different jquery theme](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)  . That's the reason i have to remove the default color/css of  anchor tag. Reason for this is if i  use one fixed color for my anchor tag, then it will not be appropriate for other theme if user select, that's the reason i want to remove the default color of anchor tag.

Here is a tag which i am using:

```
  <h2 class="post-title">
    <a href="">  Blog post title </a>  <!-- How to disable the default css color of anchor -->
 </h2>
```

If i use css on anchor then this not suitable for my others theme. Tha's the reason , i want to remove the default css color of my anchor tag.

Current mismatch default anchor behaviour on my current selected theme, you can see in this image,

[image]

Please help me to solve this issue3.

Comment: That's a weird question. You can set the color of the `a` and and select the cursor icon using CSS. If you need to disable clicking event you can use jQuery. Which parts do you need help with?

Comment: @AhmadAlfy Actually , you did not understand my doubt correctly.  i am not asking for help regarding how to use css on my anchor tag?  I am asking " how to remove the default color of anchor tag?" Please read my question once again

Comment: What makes you think that CSS is the wrong tool for *changing the way an element looks*?

Comment: @Quentin Sir, User can choose different jquery theme (http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) in my website , If i use one fixed color for my anchor tag, then it will not be appropriate for other theme, that's the reason i want to remove the default color of anchor tag

Comment: What would you do after removing default color ? may be assign a custom color instead of default color. Then why don't you simply use css rules.

Comment: @Lekhnath If i can remove the css default color, then automatically my selected theme can do its job

Comment: If your theme was doing its job, you wouldn't need to remove the default colour.

Comment: @Quentin I solved this issue using `a { color: inherit; }` . I read it from your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6722667/1684778   Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a small search, i solved my problem using

```
a { color: inherit; }
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6722667/1684778

Answer (score 1):

You will want to do this with CSS rather than JS. Use something like this in your CSS file:

```
a, a:hover, a:visited {
    /* your styles */
}
```

Comment: Sir,i am not asking for help regarding how to use css on my anchor tag?  I am asking " how to remove the default color of anchor tag?" Please read my question once again

Answer (score 0):

You can set color like this, without defining in css file. Both on load, and on theme change.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/c2yHg/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // set color on DOM ready, before theme change
    $('.post-title a').css({'color':'#000' });

    // set color when theme change
    $('#theme').on('change', function() {
        $('.post-title a').css({'color':$(this).val() });
    });   
});
```

Comment: Sir, i appreciate your answer,but its not helpfull for me. Because the theme i am selecting is from http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/   . So, i could not do as you said. If you tell me how to remove the default css color of anchor tag, then my problem will be solve