# Unable to change link color code in header

Tags: html, css, header

I have been attempting to change a link in the header to #000000, but for some reason it doesn't seem to change color. I only want to change the link in the header and not the rest of the links. Below is the example:

HTML:

```
<a class="submit-a-request" href="/hc/en-us/requests/new">Submit a request</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
 color: #022550;
 font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

This is what I attempted:

```
.submit-a-request a:link {
color: #000000;
}
```

And this:

```
a.submit-a-request {
color: #000000;
}
```

Can someone please advice? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the default link color of the html hyperlink 'a' tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722467/how-to-remove-the-default-link-color-of-the-html-hyperlink-a-tag)

Comment: when do you want the color to change?  Always, when you hover, when you click on the link?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are not targeting the right element with your CSS.  Try this:

```
a.submit-a-request {
   color: #000000;
}

/* Next line is optional - enter your own hex color for hover */
a.submit-a-request:hover { 
   color: #000000; 
}
```

Comment: That would make it the same color on hover... You need to change the hex code for the color too.

Comment: Updated with note about changing hover color.

Answer (score 0):

```css
a {
 color: green;
 font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
  
}

a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color:purple;
}

a:active{
color:orange;
}
```

```html
<a class="submit-a-request" href="#">Submit a request</a>
```