# django's urlize changing text color of entire string containing url substring

Tags: django

I am loading a long text from a database into a Django template. This string contains a url https://yyyyyy as part of the text. I use django's urlize in order to display the url as actual links, however adding urlize is causing the entire text including the link to change color to blue. Removing the urlize leaves the text as black. I only want the text to be black. How can I stop this color from changing to blue while using urlize?

Here is my implementation :

```
<p style="font-size: 15px;  color: black" class="tm-pt-30">
     {{ value.description | safe | urlize }}
</p>
```

The class `tm-pt-30` is only responsible for padding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove the default link color of the html hyperlink 'a' tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722467/how-do-i-remove-the-default-link-color-of-the-html-hyperlink-a-tag)

Comment: Something else is going on.  I just tried this, and it works on my end.  I did change it to `{{ value | safe | urlize }}` and in my view I put in the following for the value, `just text https://www.google.com and here more text`, and only the https://www.google.com is blue.  What is an example of the string you put in for value.description other than https://yyyyy?

Answer (score 0):

@raphael was right. My problem is I had wrapped the entire card containing the code in the question with `<a></a>` in order to make the whole card clickable. The fix for this was only wrapping the appropriate elements.